# MSSQL Select Active Subscribers Grouped by Day/Week

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to pull active subscribers from a table that looks like this:

```
StartDate                EndDate                  UpgradeProcessed    Cancelled  Recurring  Created
2018-09-05 09:46:30.000  2018-10-07 09:46:30.000  1                   0          1          2018-09-05 10:54:57.363
2018-09-05 09:26:32.000  2018-12-07 09:26:32.000  1                   0          1          2018-09-05 10:41:09.460
2018-09-05 09:17:49.000  2018-12-07 09:17:49.000  1                   0          1          2018-09-05 10:27:14.707
2018-09-05 09:21:16.000  2018-12-07 09:21:16.000  1                   0          1          2018-09-05 10:27:06.593
2018-09-05 09:23:04.000  2018-10-07 09:23:04.000  1                   0          1          2018-09-05 10:27:05.877
2018-09-04 09:09:42.000  2018-12-07 09:09:42.000  1                   0          1          2018-09-04 10:13:59.847
2018-09-04 09:02:29.000  2018-10-07 09:02:29.000  1                   0          1          2018-09-04 10:13:42.693
2018-09-04 09:27:23.000  2018-12-07 09:27:23.000  1                   0          1          2018-09-04 09:27:55.110
2018-09-04 08:09:31.000  2018-12-07 08:09:31.000  1                   0          1          2018-09-04 09:19:18.193
2018-09-04 08:12:20.000  2018-10-07 08:12:20.000  1                   0          1          2018-09-04 09:19:18.117
2018-09-04 08:12:20.000  2018-10-07 08:12:20.000  1                   0          1          2018-09-04 09:19:18.117
```

I want to group by day or week and each day must include any records that were active on that day even if they are included in previous rows.

In the above case we would have the following:

```
Date        Count
2018-09-05  11
2018-09-04  6
```

I can pull the data each day at a time like follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Subscriptions]
 WHERE DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0, EndDate),0) >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,Cast('2018-09-05' AS datetime)),0)
 AND DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0, Created),0) <= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,Cast('2018-09-05' AS datetime)),0)
```

I am not sure how to add a GROUP BY type clause that would include every row that is active for that day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the answer, I modified a script from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f732fcf-813e-462e-aad5-49c45bb2e581/count-of-active-customers-each-day-between-two-dates?forum=transactsql) to make a table of numbers and used the query on that page for inspiration.

```
SELECT [stats.dates].thedate, COUNT(*)
FROM   [stats.dates]
JOIN   Subscriptions ON [stats.dates].thedate >= cast([StartDate] as DATE) AND [stats.dates].thedate <= cast([EndDate] as DATE)
WHERE [stats.dates].thedate >= '2017-09-04' AND [stats.dates].thedate <= '2018-09-04'
GROUP  BY [stats.dates].thedate
```

The where clause dictates the date range you are looking to get data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT CAST(StartDate AS DATE),COUNT(1) 
FROM [Subscriptions]
WHERE DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0, EndDate),0) >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,Cast('2018-09-05' AS datetime)),0)
AND DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0, Created),0) <= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,Cast('2018-09-05' AS datetime)),0)
GROUP BY CAST(StartDate AS DATE)
```

Comment: This gives me the number of subscriptions that started on that day rather than the total active on that day.